# List, Array, Stack Queue?

Tags: list

I am very new to this programming stuff.  I am currently taking Data Structures in Java.  I have an assignment where I have to replicate a given Subway system.  I am supposed to do it in 3 classes (Station, Route and Subway).  Could someone please direct me in the right direction in regards to starting this project?  Below are my instructions.  Thank you very much.

1. Implement a class called Station that contains information about a particular station. This class should allow to set at least the name of the station. Each station is unique within the subway system.
2. Implement a class called Route that stores information about a particular route. This Route class should allow to add stations/remove stations from the route.  A route has a name.
3. Implement a class called Subway. This Subway class should allow to add and delete Route objects.
4. Implement the following subway system in your application.
5. Now, develop a method in the Subway class that given two stations passed as parameters that belongs to a Subway object, it returns a list of stations that the user will traverse to go from one station to the other. Assume that there are no loops in the system. The method signature is as follows:
   public List getRouteBetweenStations(Station a, Station b)

**Here's where I am and I'm not even sure it's correct**

```
public class **Station**
{
String station;
private final String STATION1 = "140";
private final String STATION2 = "134";
private final String STATION3 = "Unicentro";
private final String STATION4 = "100";
private final String STATION5 = "30";
private final String STATION6 = "R";
private final String STATION7 = "Marsella";
private final String STATION8 = "Mu";
private final String STATION9 = "Bosa";
private final String STATION10 = "Germania";
private final String STATION11= "19";
private final String STATION12 = "Sabana";
private final String STATION13 = "Espec";
private final String STATION14 = "F";
private final String STATION15 = "Gu";
private final String STATION16 = "Santiago";
private final String STATION17 = "SENA";
private final String STATION18 = "Timiza";

public void setStation(String stops)
{
    station = stops;
}
}


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class **Route**
{
List<String> route1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> route2 = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> route3 = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> route4 = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> route5 = new ArrayList<>();

route1.add ("140"); (**here I am getting an error here telling me that "package route1 does not exist**)
```

Again, any help you can give me is greatly appreciated

Comment: Just use Map and List.

Answer (score 0):

The subway should contain routes and routes should contain stations. When you see contains or add and delete in programming execises this most often implies you will need a list to for the classes.

What is the reason for the string constants in your Station class?